# XNA Multi-Thread Jitters

Tags: c#, multithreading, xna

brand new question.

Just implemented multi-threading into my XNA game as it was unable to keep up with using 1 processor. MT is all implemented fine and everything, however the player seems to jitter all over the spot every now and then. I originally thought it was a loss of data between the update and render, but even when i did the player update in the render it did the same thing. It's not a memory/processor issue as i'm no where near maxing out my RAM or processors. It's strange aswell because none of the other entities in the game seem to have any of these issues.

Any ideas at all??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys, i ended finding out that the way i had my MT set up i was rendering everything twice (silly mistake on my behalf i know). Thanks for the assistance though, i appreciate it :). I'll check that source article out aswell, it sounds interesting

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that springs to mind is that XNA input must be done on the main thread.

(Source: "Understanding XNA Framework Performance" GDC 2008)